# SSIS to AWS Migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssis

I am currently trying to migrate some SSIS packages to aws platform. SSIS foot print is minimal with around 15 packages, out of which only 5 have some complex data transformation logic. As of now, I am more inclined to use aws Glue as a replacement. I need to orchestrate the glue jobs and some lambda functions for which I am using step functions. Would like your opinion on using aws glue considering my use case. Are there any alternatives worth investigating?